# Why does one Sitecore site in a solution have a "lang" cookie key, and another returns null?

Tags: sitecore

I have two sites both served by one Sitecore solution, and am having a problem where the following code is forcing language embedding in the URLs of one of the two sites because the double-asterisk-enclosed piece of code below from the base LinkProvider is returning true (the "lang" cookie key returns null).

```
private bool EmbedLanguage()
{
    if (this._options.LanguageEmbedding == LanguageEmbedding.Always)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (this._options.LanguageEmbedding == LanguageEmbedding.Never)
    {
        return false;
    }
    SiteContext site = Context.Site;
    return ((site == null) || **((WebUtil.GetOriginalCookieValue(site.GetCookieKey("lang")) == null)** || this._options.EmbedLanguage(Context.Language)));
}
```

This only does this for one of the two sites, and not the other. The languageEmbedding value in the linkManager in Web.config is "asNeeded." The first (behaving) site is multi-language, and the other (not behaving) is not.

It's not clear why the behaving one is getting its "lang" cookie set, and the other is not. They're both sharing quite a bit of code, and the problematic site hasn't deviated much from the original one beyond anything other than a layout, new sublayouts, etc. The guts are pretty much the same.

Any ideas would be welcomed. Perhaps it's something really obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Clarification, it's the "lang" cookie value that's coming back null for the naughty site, not the key (sorry, late in the day).

Comment: I would avoid using 'asNeeded'. To be honest I have no idea why this setting exists. Does it make any difference if you switch this to 'always'?

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me clarify if i have understood your question correctly. 
You have 2 Sites running on same Code. (Multi-Site)
One is Multi-Language, It behaves fine (Sets the Lang cookie)
Another is Single Language, It behaves odd and does not set the Lang cookie.

How you have implemented multi-site?

It looks like you are using the mentioned function to embed language in URL in some class.
So suggesting a workaround we have implemented.

Sometime IE8 Deletes the cookie and that's the reason we have moved our multisite solution from languageEmbedding= asNeeded to Never.

We have override the LinkManager Class and when we are generating the URLs for the site we check the setting placed on the Site Home Page if the site is multi-language then we set the languageEmbedding= always. else it is already never.

This way we never face issue with language cookies.

Yes, It will not set the cookie when it is a single language site and languageEmbedding is set to never.

Answer (score 0):

The way we ended up resolving this is by adding a custom "embedLanguageInUrl" attribute to the problem site in web.config, and setting it to "never." We then used a SiteContextExtensions class to expose that value (Sitecore.Context.Site.EmbedLanguageInUrl()), and then adjust the urlOptions.LanguageEmbedding value appropriately, if needed. Seems to work great. :)